# how can i make it scrollable in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, widget, scrollview

```
import 'package:screens/Login.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'dart:ui' as prefix1;

class AppDrawer extends StatelessWidget {  
@override   Widget
build(BuildContext context) 
{
     return Drawer(
     child: ListView(
         children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             child: new Stack(

               children: <Widget>[

                 ClipPath(
                   child: Container(
                     color: Colors.blue.shade900,

                   ),
                   clipper: getClipper(),
                 ),

                 Container(
                   child: Positioned(

                     width: 300.0,
                     top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/6.7,
                     child: Column(
                       children: <Widget>[
                         Container(
                           width: 100.0,
                           height: 100.0,
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(

                             color: Colors.white,
                             image: DecorationImage(
                               image: AssetImage('assets/app1.jpg'),
                               fit: BoxFit.cover
                             ),
                             borderRadius: 
                             BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(blurRadius: 20.0, color: Colors.black)
                            ]
                            // border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 
                             1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid)
                           ),

                         ),
                         SizedBox(height: 10),
                         Text('Samuel',textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                         style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 25.0,
                           fontFamily: 'Monseratti',
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                         ),),
                         SizedBox(height: 5),
                         Text('07031024787',textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                           style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 12.0,
                               fontFamily: 'Monseratti',
                               fontStyle: FontStyle.normal
                           ),),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                           Text('Your license will expire by ', textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                           style: TextStyle(
                               fontSize: 12.0,
                               fontFamily: 'Monseratti',
                               fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                               color: Colors.red
                           ),)
                       ], 
                     ),

                   ),
                 ),


                 Positioned(
                   top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.1,
                   width: 300.0,


                   child: new Column(
                     children: <Widget>[
                       CustomListTile(Icons.dashboard, 'Login', ()=>{

                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                         return Login();
                           }))

                       }),
                       CustomListTile(Icons.home, 'My Profile', ()=>{
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                        return FeedBack();
                           }))
                       }),
                       CustomListTile(Icons.account_box, 'About', ()=>{
                             Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                         return About();
                           }))

                       }),

                     ],
                   ),
                 )

               ],


             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     );


      } } 


class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget{   IconData icon;   String text;   Function onTap;

CustomListTile(this.icon, this.text, this.onTap);

@override   Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Padding(  
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0,top: 6.0),   child: Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   border: Border( bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400)),

 ),
 child: InkWell(

   splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
   onTap: onTap,

   child: Container(
     height: 40.0,
     child: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
       children: <Widget>[
         Row(
           children: <Widget>[
             Icon(icon, color: Colors.blue),
             Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
               child:   Text(text, style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 14.0,
                 fontFamily: 'Monseratti'
               ),) ,
             )

           ],
         ),

         Icon(Icons.arrow_right)

       ],
     ),

   ),

  ) ,

 ),

);

} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your **ListView** you have to add the attribute **shrinkwrap: true**

Example:

```
ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use:**

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[]))),
```

**OR**

```
Builder(
              builder: (context) => ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    reverse: false,
                    children: <Widget>[]));
```